# Is there a word for "someone who cancelled something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I have to deal with user groups. One user may ask for some IT operation from our company at one point, but any user in his group may cancel this request.
I need a word to designate the user who is responsible for the request to abort the request so I can use it as a column header in our database.

```
reference |  abortionist  |  cancelled_at
xt9pj27x  |   John Doe    | 2018-06-01 15:00:00
```

I have been told to use *abortionist* but it has strong connotations with abortion.

Comment: what kind of requests specifically?

Comment: and is this in light of the person who was given the request?

Comment: @esu I have edited the question. I that enough for you to understand the need ? thank you

Comment: _Abortionist_ is a horrific word in this context.  I would prefer "cancelled_by", which also makes it more obvious what that person's role is.

Comment: "aborted_by" should work.  *Aborter* would be the word, but it again primarily brings images of MTP.

Comment: This explains the legal differences between termination, cancellation, revocation, and rescission. https://www.translegal.com/lesson/7035

Comment: @Kris The reason I'd prefer "cancelled_by" is that it relates to the "cancelled_at" column.

Comment: negated_by is another option; also reversed_by; countermanded

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our help center specifically states that choosing names for things in computer programs is out of scope for our site.

Comment: @tchrist To me, withdrawer sounds like the answer I was looking for (see accepted answer last comment).

Comment: Agreed *abortionist* sounds terrible, perhaps *aborted* would be slightly better - https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aborter

Comment: Btw, *cancel* and *abort* may not be quite the same, at least in the given context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider *vetoer*.

> **vetoer** *noun*
> (see veto)
> ‘There is some grey area on what ‘technical’ can mean, but the vetoer receives the benefit of the doubt.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vetoer)
>
> **veto** *verb*
> 1.1 Refuse to accept or allow.
> ‘Often the artist or the gallery might veto an idea like that.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/veto)

Wikipedia touches on the 'unilateral stop' aspect of the veto in the context of politics:

> A veto – Latin for "I forbid" – is the power (used by an officer of the state, for example) to unilaterally stop an official action, especially the enactment of legislation.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veto)

Here is an example of the term used in the context of programming:

> If called, signifies that the calling check wishes to veto the merge.
> [- Atlassian Developers](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/javadoc/4.0.7/spi/reference/com/atlassian/bitbucket/scm/pull/MergeRequest.html)

In the context you describe, the person who made the request is included in the group that has the power to withdraw the request, so it's possible for someone to withdraw their own request. It sounds a bit odd to say that one *vetoes* one's own actions, but it is not unheard of. Here's an example:

> The **United Nations Security Council "veto power"** refers to the power of the permanent members of the United Nations Security Council (China, France, Russia, United Kingdom, and United States) to veto any "substantive" resolution.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_veto_power)

Comment: _Veto_ is not the same as _abort_ or _cancel_; it implies the need for consent, ie someone has a veto that they can make use of. And it is not a common term in computing.

Comment: @OliverMason I've added an example that matches the OP's context. I'm not sure what you mean by the remark about implied consent. In the OP's context, the IT request is implicitly (or maybe even explicitly) subject to the group's consent. How is this different from a veto? Regarding being uncommon in computing - I've provided an example of the term used in the context of programming.

Comment: Hard to put into words; I would use veto only if everybody sees the request, and can object to it. So by not objecting they agree. Not quite the same as checking a queue and then cancelling something. Your example is from a computing context, true, but the term _veto_ is not normally used for stopping requests.

Comment: @OliverMason Actually, if it can be *cancelled*, it's not really a 'request' in the usual sense; it's closer to an 'order' or 'command'. Requests are more properly *withdrawn* than *cancelled*.

Comment: @OliverMason About queues and limited exposure - I'm not sure where you got that from. It doesn't appear in the question, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Then `withdrawer` and `withdrawn_at` look like the the perfect couple, isn't it !?@Lawrence

Answer (score 2):

A better option would be to use "cancelled_by" in analogy to the following column "cancelled_at". This makes explicit that it is the same operation you are talking about.

I do realise that it is not a single word, but given the context I would think it to be a better option.

The term *[abortionist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abortionist)* is almost exclusively linked with the medical procedure of terminating pregnancies; it would be very much out of place in the context of cancelling IT requests.

Comment: "cancelled_by" isn't an English word.

Comment: @Lawrence but in this situation it would make the best column heading.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about topics explicitly out of scope for EL&U: "*Naming, including naming programming variables/classes*". There are strong sentiments against SWRs on EL&U, though many are happy to retain *good* SWRs. I'd suggest keeping SWR posts to actual English terms and away from programming labels/variables/etc. The main rationale is that those labels can really be anything - there's no real 'best answer' for them. Nevertheless, I like the parallel you mentioned. As a compromise, you could suggest a '2-word' phrase "cancelled by".

Comment: I guess there is no "single" english word for th

Comment: @Stphane There is - "vetoer" is one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using abort is acceptable and correct but use "abort" only or if you prefer using phrasal verb, you can use "call off"